# Converting UTC time string to UTC milliseconds

Tags: java, kotlin, java-time

I am getting a time string that is the sunrise/sunset times in UTC in format `HH:mm`

example:

`09:35`

Currently I am doing this to convert the given time to the current date UTC using the `java.time` library

```
val utcZoneId = ZoneId.of("UTC")
val now = Instant.now()
val dateTimeFormater:DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").withZone(utcZoneId)
val date = dateTimeFormater.format(now)

val fullDateSunrise = "${date}T${data[0].sunrise}:00"
val local = LocalDateTime.parse(fullDateSunrise, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
val final = local.atZone(utcZoneId)
val utcSunrise = final.toInstant().toEpochMilli()

val fullDateSunset = "${date}T${data[0].sunset}:00"
val local2 = LocalDateTime.parse(fullDateSunset, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
val final2 = local2.atZone(utcZoneId)
val utcSunset = final2.toInstant().toEpochMilli()
```

I then pass the UTC milliseconds back the the client once I have them

It works how I need it to but I can help but feel there must be an easier way than getting a formatted UTC date string and combining that with the given time and then converting that to an actual DateTime object.

So the question is, is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you definitely don't need to parse back and forth to strings. I assume an input of `09:35` means: At 09:35, local time, the sun will rise. Note that you're confusing things; UTC is a zone, an input like `09:35` is zoneless. I doubt this stamp represent 'UTC'; it would mean that the correct value for the sunrise today for Tokyo is `-5:25`, as it'll be `19:25`, the previous day, in the UTC timezone when the sun rose in tokyo today.

Once you stop using the UTC zone it becomes muuuch simpler:

```
DateTimeFormatter TIME_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
LocalDateTime sunriseToday = LocalDateTime.now().with(LocalTime.parse("04:35", TIME_FORMAT));
ZonedDateTime inTokyo = sunriseToday.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"));
return inTokyo.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Note that this would return the exact moment in time when the sun rises in tokyo. Printing it as an ISO stamp, that'd be `2020-06-09T19:35Z`.

If you really want the epoch-millis that match `2020-06-10T04:35Z` - which to be clear **makes no sense**, that is *NOT* when the sun rose in tokyo at all today! - then...

```
DateTimeFormatter TIME_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
LocalDateTime sunriseToday = LocalDateTime.now().with(LocalTime.parse("04:35", TIME_FORMAT));
ZonedDateTime inTokyo = sunriseToday.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"));
ZoneDateTime thisMakesNoSense = inTokyo.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC);
return thisMakesNoSense.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Comment: the time from the API is indeed the time in `UTC` as the time that the client converts the UTC milliseconds to end up being correct after adding in the clients local time zone. So for example I am testing this in timezone `America/New_York` and the offset is 4 hours which then corresponds to the correct time from UTC

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert `String`s, use a `ZonedDateTime` instead and provide a desired zone.

Use some `fun` like this one:

```kotlin
fun convertToEpochMillis(time: String, zoneId: ZoneId): Long {
    // parse the time to a LocalTime
    val localTime = LocalTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"))
    // create a ZonedDateTime from the current date, the parsed time the given time zone
    val zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), localTime, zoneId)
    // then return the representation of the instant in epoch millis
    return zonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli()
}
```

and use it in a `fun main()` as follows

```kotlin
fun main() {
    // define / receive a time
    val time = "09:35"
    // and a zone identifier
    var zone = "UTC"

    // use the method
    val utcSunriseMillis = convertToEpochMillis(time, ZoneId.of(zone))
    // and print a result statement
    println("Sunrise time ${time} in ${zone} is ${utcSunriseMillis}")

    // change the zone and do the same again with a different zone, just to see what happens...
    zone = "America/Los_Angeles"
    val laSunriseMillis = convertToEpochMillis(time, ZoneId.of(zone))
    println("Sunrise time ${time} in ${zone} is ${laSunriseMillis}")
}
```

which then prints today (=> 2020-06-10)

```
Sunrise time 09:35 in UTC is 1591781700000
Sunrise time 09:35 in America/Los_Angeles is 1591806900000
```